# How to sort some part of css in one line and another part in multiple lines

Tags: css, formatting, sublimetext3, csscomb

I'd like to make a custom config for CSScomb that can sort part of the css in one line and part of it as the default, multiple line sort.

The css that I'd like to be sorted in one line should refer to font styling.
Right now if I use CSScomb it will format the CSS something like this:

```
p
{
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 18px;       

    color: #484848;
}
```

I'd like this to look like:

```
p { font-family: 'Proxima Nova',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 100; line-height: 18px; color: #484848; }
```

But other properties that are not font specific to be formated as the default CSScomb values.

Would also appreciate if someone could explain where to put the custom config file (.csscomb.json) in windows 8.1 so that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define it in Home directory or root directory of your project. As another option, since you use Sublime Text 3, you can define it in 
Preferences > Package Settings > CSScomb